# How can I make Nautilus sorting ignore the word "The" or "A" at the beginning of file and folder names?

Tags: nautilus, sort, style

I have a rather large library of media and it gets annoying looking for something when I forget that the "official" name of the movie, artist, song, etc begins with the words "The" or "A".  So, for example, if I have a file like:

*The Lord of the Rings- Fellowship of the Ring.mp4*

I would like it to be sorted by skipping the word "The" in this title, so the file would be sorted like the following:

*Lord of the Rings- Fellowship of the Ring.mp4*

However, I don't want to remove the word "The" in this instance from the name.  Basically, I'd like the sorting found in Finder in OS X.  Is this possible?  I'd only want it to affect Nautilus.  If I run `ls` for example from CLI, I don't want that to ignore the word "The" or "A".

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS right now (Nautilus version 3.4.2).

Comment: I'm afraid Dennis is correct, you'd have to code it yourself. A bash script wouldn't be hard to do, though. I can see if I can do something, would that be enough?

Answer (score 1):

Neat idea. However, it would require changing the source code of nautilus and recompiling it, as there's no configuration item that allows you to do this.